# Does anyone have any idea how to connect manychat with dialogflow without 3rd party integration

Tags: dialogflow-es, manychats

Hi guys I want to connect my manychat to dialogflow without any 3rd party service like Janis.ai

I want to connect both of them directly without any mediator

please help

Comment: What have you tried sofar ?

Comment: I just googled "connect manychat with dialogflow" and, for example, here is the first link: https://medium.com/janis/how-to-make-your-manychat-bots-smarter-with-dialogflow-d74712252508#:~:text=The%20first%20step%20to%20adding,to%20save%20your%20AI%20agent.. Stack overflow may not be your best bet here.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that explains how you can connect ManyChat to Dialogflow: https://chatimize.com/connect-manychat-dialogflow/